# Как записать ответ от пользователя в ТГ боте в переменную?

Tags: python, telebot, переменные, бот

Как записать в переменную ответ от пользователя. В переменную age.

```
age = None

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("17")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("18")
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("19")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет, {0.first_name}! Сколько тебе лет?".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Вам " + age + "лет")

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Можете попробовать `age = message.text`

Comment: Просто как совет, используйте aiogram и машину состояний.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_pPNlXMzsw&t=9s

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add("17", "18", "19")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f"Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}!\n "
                                           f"Сколько тебе лет?",
                     reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, input_age)


def input_age(message: types.Message):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Вам  {message.text} + лет")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Вы ввели не число")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, input_age)
```